# MultipartFile Wrapper Object woks as @ModelAttribute but not as @RequestParam

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartfile

I created a spring RestController to process fileUpload from a react js UI.

To be able to use custom validations by `@Validated` annotation, had to wrap the MultipartFile into a class, I named it as `UploadedFile`. Created my Post Handler method with argument as `@ModelAttribute`.
Everything works fine.

`validate(target, error)` method in my custom validator is called and inside POST handler method, `UploadedFile` object has the multipart file containing the uploaded document..

Here is a perfectly working code

```
 @PostMapping("/file")
    public ResponseEntity<?> receiveFile(@Validated  @ModelAttribute UploadedFile file) {
  }

@Getter
@Setter
public class UploadedFile {
    MultipartFile file;
}
// one CustomValidator class and webDataBinder.addValidators(customValidator) in controller


multipart.enabled=true //in application.properties
```

---

So far everything works as expected, Problem arise when

Someone asked me that, `@ModelAttribute` is a spring MVC construct, as this is a microservice, which in future, apart from my React UI, will cater to other api requests too, so I should use `@RequestParam` instead of `@ModelAttribute`.

So I changed `@ModelAttribute` to `@RequestParam` as follows

```
  @PostMapping("/file")
    public ResponseEntity<?> receiveFile(@Validated  @RequestParam(name = "file") UploadedFile file)
```

But now I get below exception

```
     Failed to convert value of type 
    'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile'
     to required type 'com.x.x.x.UploadedFile'; 
     nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
     Cannot convert value of type 
    'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' 
     to required type 'com.x.x.x.UploadedFile': 
     no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

If, for `@RequestParam`, I change type as `MultipartFile` instead of `UploadedFile`  then my posthandler gets called but the custom Validator doesn't gets called by spring before handler call,
I tried to use instanceOf `MultiPartFile` in validator supports method by still no avail.

```
@PostMapping(value="/file" )
    public ResponseEntity<?> receiveFile(@Validated  @RequestParam(name = "file") MultipartFile file)
```

---

I've the work around to explicitly call the custom validator method by code as first line in POST handler, so I dont need a solution **MY QUESTION IS**

How come, without adding any custom `@Bean` or any extra external dependencies everything works fine with `@ModelAttribut`e, but merely changing the annotation `@RequestParam` doesn't work.

Comment: Ignore the comment and use `@ModelAttribute` the `@RequestParam` is as much a Spring construct as the `@ModelAttribute`. What is used on the client side doesn't matter as that is all HTTP anyway, how the server handles that isn't a concern of the client and doesn't change how the server works. Also `@RequestParam` works to convert a single parameter to a type, spring doesn't know how to convert your `file` parameter to an `UploadedFile`. When using `@ModelAttribute` it will bind the `file` parameter to a property `file` on the `UploadedFile`. Both annotations are quite different beasts!

Comment: @M.Deinum If needed, I'm looking for a reference PropertyEditor implementation to make this work with `@RequestParam`. but couldn't find any.

Comment: You shouldn't, the person giving the comment doesn't understand how the web works. Just use `@ModelAttribute` which is designed for that.